# \begin{table} makes table disappear

Tags: tables

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper]{geometry}  
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel} 
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{multirow}
 \usepackage{caption}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }
\special{papersize=8.5in,11in}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[caption = false]{subfig}
\usepackage{geometry}

\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c c|}
\hline
    Parameter & Intensity [mW] \\ 
 \hline \hline 
 $I_0(0,0)$ & $0.23$ \\
 \hline
 $I_0(0,0)$ & $0.23$ \\
 \hline
 $I_0(0,0)$ & $0.23$ \\
 \hline
 $I_0(0,0)$ & $0.23$ \\
 \hline
 $I_0(0,0)$ & $0.23$ \\
 \hline
 $I_0(0,0)$ & $0.23$ \\
 \hline
\end{tabular}
    \caption{Intensidades}
    \label{intSt}
 \end{table}
```

When I remove `\begin{table}` & `\end{table}` the tables does appear, however I cant add `\caption` or `\label`. Does anyone knows how to make the table appear with `\begin{table}` & `\end{table}`?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! The table is there on my machine after adding `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`.

Comment: I got the same results as @marmot - are you sure it's disappeared and not moved?

Comment: 100% sure, I use \ref{insSt} somewhere else and it appears as: '??', just as if the table didnt exists

Comment: I also began a new documment and it works, very stange!

Comment: Ohhhh, we thought you were talking about the whole table itself, not the reference. Have you compiled twice?

Comment: actually the whole table disappears, the ref was just a 'confirmation' that it wasnt placed anywhere else

Comment: There are now two contradicting statement, "I also began a new documment and it works..." and "actually the whole table disappears...". Which one is correct?

Comment: the whole table disappears in the original document, but when I create a new document and copy-paste the code, it appears just fine..

Comment: I believe the problem is related to the use of: \begin{multicols}{2} \end{multicols{2}

Comment: that is why every question should have an example of the problem, nothing in the code you posted is related to the problem or the answer.

Comment: If you put a `table` inside a `multicols` environment the `.log` file will tell you that `Package multicol Warning: Floats and marginpars not allowed inside 'multicols' environment!.`

Answer (score 2):

I am unable to replicate the problem you describe once I add the instructions `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` to your code. I can only assume (and hope...) that the table which you're actually trying to typeset different from the "dummy" table you posted.

At any rate, I'd make an effort to improve the intelligibility of the table, say, by omitting all `\hline` directives and, instead, loading the `booktabs` package and drawing far fewer, but well-spaced lines. Switching from a `tabular` to an `array` environment would improve the readability of the code, by allowing a serious reduction in the number of `$` symbols used throughout the table.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper]{geometry}  
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{blindtext} % do you really need this?
\usepackage[spanish]{babel} 
\usepackage{tabularx}
%%\usepackage{array} % is loaded automatically by 'tabularx'
\usepackage{adjustbox} % do you reall need this package?
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{multirow}
%%\usepackage{caption}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }
%%\special{papersize=8.5in,11in}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{multicol}
%%\usepackage[caption = false]{subfig}
%%\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs} % <-- new
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
$\begin{array}{@{}cc@{}}
  \toprule
  $Parameter$ & $Intensity [mW]$ \\ 
  \midrule 
  I_0(0,0) & 0.23 \\
  I_1(0,0) & 0.23 \\
  I_2(0,0) & 0.23 \\[0.75ex] 
  I_4(0,0) & 0.23 \\ 
  I_4(0,0) & 0.23 \\ 
  I_5(0,0) & 0.23 \\
  \bottomrule
\end{array}$
\caption{Intensidades}\label{intSt}
 \end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: so far i didn't see the use `$Parameter$ & $Intensity [mW]$ \\ ` for making `Parameter` and `Intensity [mW]` normal text. is this somewehere described?

Comment: @Zarko - Since I'm using an `array` environments, the contents of a `c`-type column is in math mode by default. Writing `$Parameter$` exits math mode at the start and re-enters it at the end of the cell. Another way to achieve the objective of rendering "Parameter" in text mode would be to input it as `\mbox{Parameter}` -- 5 keystrokes more than `$Parameter$`...

Comment: thank you very much. i suspect this, but i was not sure, if this is allowed. good to know :-)

Comment: @Zarko: Ah... I will remove my comment then.

Answer (score 1):

fixed using:

```
    \begin{wraptable}{l}{0.7\linewidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c | c|}
    \hline
    Parámetros & Intensidades [mW] \\ 
    \hline  
    $I(0,0)$ & $0.23$ \\
     $I(\frac{\pi}{4},0)$ & $0.25$ \\
     $I(\frac{\pi}{2},0)$ & $0.27$ \\
     $I(\frac{3\pi}{4},0)$ & $0.26$ \\
     $I(\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{\pi}{2})$ & $0.23$ \\
     $I(\frac{3\pi}{4},\frac{\pi}{2})$ & $0.23$ \\
     \hline
    \end{tabular}
         \caption{Intensidades}
          \label{intSt}
\end{wraptable}
```

Comment: how is your answer related to your question? please first make your code example in question as well in answer compilable.