# \begin table in muticol environment makes table go poof

Tags: tables, floats, formatting, multicol

This has been asked before: [\begin{table} makes table disappear](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/416044/begintable-makes-table-disappear?rq=1)

Without a compilable example, so I made a mwe. I want a captioned table on a multicol environment, To that effect I wrote this:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{multicol, caption}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\setlength{\parskip}{0em}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin={2cm, 2cm}]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem*{lemma}{Lemma}
\usepackage[ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
I am a test 

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
    \hline
    & Average Delta \\
    \hline
    Sphere & 8.77237e-07 \\
    WGS84 & 1.03976e-07 \\
    Ellipsoid of revolution & 1.20783e-06 \\
    Arbitrary Ellipsoid & 0.00126442 \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{\label{tab:StabilityResults} Average delta between the original curve and one obtained after 5 consecutive decompositions and reconstructions repeated 10 000 times.}


\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

This compiles with an error (because the caption makes no sense as it's not in the correct environment) and produces this:

[image]

So you can try to add a table environment:

```
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
    \hline
    & Average Delta \\
    \hline
    Sphere & 8.77237e-07 \\
    WGS84 & 1.03976e-07 \\
    Ellipsoid of revolution & 1.20783e-06 \\
    Arbitrary Ellipsoid & 0.00126442 \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{\label{tab:StabilityResults} Average delta between the original curve and one obtained after 5 consecutive decompositions and reconstructions repeated 10 000 times.}
\end{table}
```

Which compiles without terminal errors but magically poofs away the table:

[image]

That's the entire document, so there's no chance of it just going somewhere else. Any suggestions on getting the table captioned?

Comment: From the `multicols` manual: "   At  the moment only  page-widefloats (i.e., star-forms) can be used within the scope of the environment."

Comment: See also: [multicol and figures](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12262/134144)

Comment: For your final question: use the `capt-of` package https://ctan.org/pkg/capt-of?lang=en, this will allow you to insert captions for things that are not floating.